# Can I register a CME Notification from a TBB?

Tags: 2013-sp1, gui-extensions, templating, workflow

I would like to throw a notification message in the CME message center from my workflow external activity TBB.

I am just trying to do this but not sure this is possible. I can do this with help of event system or GUI extension. But trying to see if I can do it with the TBB (workflow external activity) itself.

So, I am trying to get the Tridion Page object and register some notification as below. But I am not able to get the Page object. Is there a way to do this?

```
page = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "script", "<script type='text/javascript'>$messages.registerNotification(\"Hello world\");</script>");
```

Comment: I suggest you **edit** your question and supply a few more details like your TBB code, since the two lines of code you have added now don't give any detail.

Comment: Bart i can put, i have automatic decision activity in that i am just checking the user. If the user is expected then am just finishing the activity. If the user is not the expected one. i want to throw the notification and finish the activity. so, trying to throw the notification in the message center.

Comment: May I ask why you're not using Groups for this - or is there some specific business logic? We had a scenario where the approval of step X could not be undertaken by the approver of step X-1 - in which case we sent a notification to the CMS given them a jolly good telling off.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented the logic for component/page update notification using event handle.

please find below source code.

> Step1:
>
> Create a new SDLResponder.js file

```
SDLWeb.ContentManager.SDLResponder = function SDLResponder() {
    Tridion.OO.enableInterface(this, "Tridion.ContentManager.SDLResponder");
    this.addInterface("Tridion.MarshallableObject");
    this.addInterface("Tridion.InitializableObject");
    this.initialize();
};

SDLWeb.ContentManager.SDLResponder.IDENTIFIER = "tcm:SDLResponder";

SDLWeb.ContentManager.SDLResponder.prototype._initialize = function SDLResponder$_initialize() {
    this.callBase("Tridion.InitializableObject", "_initialize");
    SDLWeb.Web.UI.Core.NotificationBroadcaster.getInstance().addEventListener("notification", this.getDelegate(this.handleNotification));
};

SDLWeb.ContentManager.SDLResponder.prototype.handleNotification = function SDLResponder$handleNotification(event) {
    if (event.data !== null) {
        var id = Tridion.ContentManager.UserSettings.getJsonUserSettings(true).User["@ID"];
        var data = event.data;
        if (data.details.userId !== null && data.details !== undefined) {

            if (data.details !== null && data.details.userId !== null && data.details.userId == id) {
                switch (data.action) {
                    case "PageSave":                       
                        //MessageCenter$registerNotification(title, description, local, modal, htmlDescription) for hyperlinks to work send true for html description
                        $messages.registerNotification("Notification", "" + data.details.messageNotification, true, null, true);
                        break;
                    case "ComponentSave":

                        //MessageCenter$registerNotification(title, description, local, modal, htmlDescription) for hyperlinks to work send true for html description
                        $messages.registerNotification("Notification", "" + data.details.messageNotification, true, null, true);
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
};

if (!$models.getFromRepository(SDLWeb.ContentManager.SDLResponder.IDENTIFIER)) {
    $models.createInRepository(SDLWeb.ContentManager.SDLResponder.IDENTIFIER, "SDLWeb.ContentManager.SDLResponder");
};
```

> Step2: Added below line into editor.config:

```
<cfg:file type="script">/Notifications/SDLResponder.js</cfg:file>
```

**

> Event handler code for component update:

**

```
 public void SendSoftNotificationMessage(Component component)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string notificationmessage = string.Empty;
            string softNotificationMessage = string.Empty;
            string emailnotificatioinmessage = string.Empty;          
            Dictionary<string, object> componentDic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            var session = component.Session;
            componentDic.Add("userId", session.AccessToken.Id.ToString());
            componentDic.Add("reasons", emptyarray);                   
            softNotificationMessage = string.Format(EventHandlerConstants.Message, component.Title ));          
            notificationmessage = string.Format(EventHandlerConstants.SoftNotificationMessage, component.Title, softNotificationMessage);
            componentDic.Add("messageNotification", notificationmessage);
            string jsonString = serializer.Serialize((object)componentDic);
            var message = new NotificationMessage
            {
                Action = "ComponentSave",
                SubjectIds = new[] { component.Id.ToString() },
                Details = jsonString
            };
            session.NotificationsManager.BroadcastNotification(message);         
        }
```